# c++ boost checking for an empty dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, segmentation-fault, eigen

I have a class which contains a dynamic `Eigen::MatrixXd`. Some of the constructors for my class do not need to 'resize' this array, i.e. there is no need for this data member if the object is initialized in specific cases. I'd however like to check if this data member(`eigen_matrix`) has been populated. Checking using:

```
if(eigen_matrix.size()>0){
        //do specific operations on eigen_matrix
}
```

seems to end up seg-faulting. Is there another way for me to test for an empty dynamic array?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Eigen::MatrixXd` extensively and I check for non-zero size like

```
if( foo.size() != 0)
```

I never got segfault, and you should not get a segfault in your case. Probably the segfault comes from other line of code (like assigning stuff to an empty matrix or overflowing the rows/cols). Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

If the `.size()` call is failing, it is highly probably that you are accessing `eigen_matrix` through a null reference. Check `&eigen_matrix` at the beginning of the scope where your trying to use it.